# Boolean tests with integers in C

Tags: c

The following works in C without giving a warning:

```
int holding_variable = (-5 && 1);
int holding_variable = (1 && 1);
int holding_variable = (0 && 0);
```

Yet the following gives warning (numbers are greater than 1):

```
int holding_variable = (-5 && 2);
int holding_variable = (2 && 2);
```

An example warning would be:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main.out && ./main.out
main.c:66:28: warning: use of logical '&&' with constant operand [-Wconstant-logical-operand]
    int holding_variable = (1 && -1);
                              ^  ~~
main.c:66:28: note: use '&' for a bitwise operation
    int holding_variable = (1 && -1);
                              ^~
                              &
main.c:66:28: note: remove constant to silence this warning
    int holding_variable = (1 && -1);
                             ~^~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

What accounts for the difference in the above two categories as to why the first will execute but the second ones will not?

Comment: Please include the exact warning you get. Each compiler has their own rules.

Comment: What is 'i'? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: And what is `i > 1`? There is no `i`

Comment: @machine_1 updated with an example error.

Comment: I get the `-Wconstant-logical-operand` when compiling with clang, and it suggests that the compiler thinks that you might want to use bitwise and. My suspicion is that the reason 0 and 1 does not give the warning is that the compiler converts them to booleans.

Comment: You didn't show the actual warning, only the note that follows it. Post a [mcve].

Comment: overreach.   disable warnings from the code generator (clang, gcc) and employ a proper static analyzer (lint) if that is what you want.   This is the difference between a project and a product.

Comment: The compiler warnings are intended to catch common programming mistakes, while remaining silent about common programming idioms. They don't always get it right. OTOH, I don't see anything in your examples that indicates that they got it wrong.

Comment: You're being bitten by an overzealous linter.  Using `&&` outside of a control expression for an `if`, `while`, `for`, etc., is unusual, and the compiler is basically saying "are you *sure* that's what you meant, because a lot of people write `&&` when they mean `&` in this context".  It's similar to the warnings you get if you write `if ( a = b )` - you fully intend for `a` to be updated as part of the condition, but more often than not people meant to do a comparison and wrote `=` instead of `==`, so most compilers issue an "are you sure" warning.

Comment: '1' is true, '2' is also true. But why '2'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Not 0 value is true, like below

```
int main(){ 

    int i;
    for(i=-3;i<=3;i++){
        if(i){
            printf("True :%d\n",i);
        }else{
            printf("False :%d\n",i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So if you don't want warn using & is right in your case

because  0 & X is always 0

and add a function if you only want 0 or 1

```
int BeBool(int a){
    if(a){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

int holding_variable = BeBool(2&2);

instead int holding_variable = (2 && 2);

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int BeBool(int a){
    if(a){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){ 

    int i;
    for(i=-3;i<=3;i++){
        if(i){
            printf("True :%d\n",i);
        }else{
            printf("False :%d\n",i);
        }
    }
    int holding_variable = BeBool(2&2);
    printf("Value :%d\n",holding_variable);
    return 0;
}
```